# Redirecting Error with google load balancer

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, redirect, ssl-certificate-errors

I'm trying to setup Google Load Balancer and couldn't get it work. It produces either 502 or 302 error.

Wanting to direct www to non-www, http to https.

This is my rewrite rule

```
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
    <VirtualHost _default_:80>
      DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
      Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
      <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyPass /.well-known !
      </IfModule>
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)?$
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)?$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Google Load Balancer has only 1 backend service. Backend is configured for HTTP and frontend is HTTPS with 60s timeout.

- The instance is accessible via both instance's IP and load balancer's IP
- www to non-www is not working.
- Http gives a 404 error.
- https gives a 502 / 302 error.

Are the rewrite rules all wrong?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you are trying to configure http to https in a external HTTP(S) Load Balancer, it seems that you set up a URL Rewrite rules in apache instead redirects in GCP, based on the [traffic management](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/traffic-management) for HTTP(S) Load Balancers, [redirects](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/traffic-management#redirects) includes the capability to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS requests, here’s an [example](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect) to set up http-https redirect